# How does an appexchange user request for more licenses

Tags: appexchange

A customer has installed our managed package with a single user license and they now want to increase the no of licenses to 2.

How do they add one more user license?

Answer (score 1):

You have the license record in your LMA correct? you can increase the number of licenses on that record, it will automatically reflect on your customer's org

Comment: i did try that and i got an error message when i saved it  " Cannot edit Allowed Licenses on a license that is Provisioned. Please contact Support for more details.: Allowed Licenses"